# Yammer API "body_blank" error, but body property specified

Tags: yammer

When posting a Message to Yammer's API, I sometimes get this error response:

```
{"body":["Please include a message"],"code":"body_blank"}
```

But the payload that I'm POSTing to the endpoint looks something like this:

```
{
     "broadcast": true,
     "og_url": "https://example.com",
     "og_title": "¡Viva México!",
     "og_description": "Thank you Miriam for bringing the fun to Cinco de Mayo. I had a blast making Salsa last night and can't wait until lunch time to see what everyone brings!! Lunch starts at 9 right?",
     "og_image": "https://example.com/image.svg",
     "body": "[[user:1523644839]] received the badge, ¡Viva México!, from Moose."
}
```

The `body` parameter is where the text of the message body is supposed to go, according to the [Yammer API docs](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/messages-json-post).

I also doubled checked that the POST request has `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` specified. This error only occurs occasionally too, plenty of other Messages get posted just fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Announcements don't support Open Graph Objects. That is likely why you are seeing that error.

Also- be mindful of using scripts to post announcements. They can viewed as spammy by users in the network.

Comment: Not sure what an announcement is, couldn't find any reference to it in the API docs. This is a message anyways, and according to their docs, Open Graph objects work fine, and I've confirmed that they do post.

And thanks for the heads up, I do agree. In this case, this is a specifically requested customer feature.

Comment: "broadcast": true <-- this makes the post an announcement which is a different kind of Yammer post. It currently doesn't support Open Graph Objects. Leaving broadcast off should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to deploy that change and hope we don't see anymore body_blank errors

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it, still getting the same error.

Comment: This worked for me as the payload:



{
     "og_url": "https://example.com",
     "og_title": "¡Viva México!",
     "og_description": "Thank you Miriam for bringing the fun to Cinco de Mayo. I had a blast making Salsa last night and can't wait until lunch time to see what everyone brings!! Lunch starts at 9 right?",
     "og_image": "https://example.com/image.svg",
     "body": "[[user:USER_ID_HERE]] received the badge, ¡Viva México!, from Moose."
}

sorry for the lousy formatting - I couldn't get the code markdown to work. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. My code used to work, but all of a sudden it started raising 400 (Bad Request) error, and the response body was: {"body":["Please include a message"],"code":"body_blank"}.
My fix was making sure I had "content-type: application/json" as part of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Well I faced the same issue and there is apparently no clear reason as to why it happens. Lucky for us we have a package called [yammy](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/python-sdk) offered by yammer to smooth things out.

Here is the [Git](https://github.com/yammer/yam-python). and here is the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/yampy/quickstart.html) with is fairly simple.